# JQuery & PHP - How to save reordered group of divs within a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sorting

I know there are similar questions out there, but I can't seem to find one that answers my particular problem. I have a form that contains a group of divs that are generated based on a JSON array (that is saved in a separate JSON file).

I'm using Bootstrap for the design foundation (I'll spare you the lengthy HTML markups) & the "sortable" function of JQueryUI to reorder the list. The problem I can't seem to solve is how to save that order when I update the JSON.

This is my current setup:

```
<script>
var wrapper=$('#eventWrapper');
$(wrapper).sortable();
$(wrapper).disableSelection();
var add_button=$('#addEventButton');

$.getJSON('events.json',function(events){
  var count=Object.keys(events).length;
  if(count>0){
    for(var i=1;i<=count;i++){
      //Load the input values
      var name=events[i].name;
      var date=events[i].date;
      //Build the event card
      var currentEvent='<div class="ui-state-default">...<input type="text" name="event'+i+'[name]" value="'+name+'">...<input type="text" name="event'+i+'[date]" value="'+date+'">...<button class="remove_event">Remove event</button></div>';
      //Newest event on top, plz!
      $(wrapper).prepend(currentEvent);
    }
  };
  var x=count;
  $(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    x++;
    var newEvent='<div class="ui-state-default">...<input type="text" name="event'+x+'[name]">...<input type="text" name="event'+x+'[date]">...<button class="remove_event">Remove event</button></div>';
    $(wrapper).prepend(newEvent);
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_event",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
$('#updateBtn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'updateList.php',
    data:$('#eventForm').serialize(),
    success:...
  });
});
```

And for the updateList.php:

```
<?php
$json=json_encode($_POST);
$file='events.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json);
if(file_exists($file)){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>0));
}
?>
```

The #eventForm encapsulates the series of events first built by the JSON then added/deleted/reordered by the user (click/drag using sortable(), remove button, and add event button). How would I update the **x** value of the input array to reflect the reordered list before or when the form is submitted?

Comment: Solved this problem by banging my head against the wall until the wall gave way

Comment: it seems like your for loop should be started from var i=0 and secondly, it should be handled by using $.each function of jquery to reduce line code. It's not a problem of for loop function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved my own problem! Here's what I did if anyone else comes across a similar problem in their project:

I changed this bit of code:

```
for(var i=1;i<=count;i++){
      //Load the input values
      var name=events[i].name;
      var date=events[i].date;
```

to this:

```
for(i in events){
    var name=events[i].name;
    var date=events[i].date;
```

Simple change in the "for" loop makes a world of difference!

I wasn't saving incorrectly, but rather reading the content from the JSON file incorrectly. If the user reorders the cards [1,2,3,4] as [3,2,4,1], I previously read the JSON file as [3,2,4,1] based on the given input "names".

Now on reload, the old [3,2,4,1] is now read sequentially as [1,2,3,4], ignoring whatever the input "names" may be.